# What a great piece of code!

Tags: feature-request, voting, source-code

This idea is about saving a valuable pieces of code from the ocean of the questions that everyday are posted on Stack Overflow .
It could be like an upvote, but only on the code box, maybe also with an optional short comment.
In my idea only the people who earned, at least, the silver badge on that language can voteup the code.
Then, of course, it's needed the ability to search on this library.

(i hope it's not duplicated)

Comment: I will never get the point here on meta :P

Answer (score 5):

It's a nice idea, but not really necessary IMO. In my experience, the normal upvoting/downvoting process for answers already does this. Bad code is *very* likely to get pointed out, commented on, and downvoted, and good code gets upvoted if it is part of a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I appreciate the time taken to churn out a fantastic piece of answer-centric code, many other good answers do not come in the form of codes. There are also lots of comments which turned out to be 'better' than the answers. We wouldn't want a 'What a line of comment!", do we?

Comment: We already vote on comments ;)

Comment: @voyager, you are spot on for this. The tooltip for the comment upvote is "this is a great comment". Ooops.. I stepped on my own foot.